# Transitivity of the Limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, relations

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions of a single, real variable. Write $f \rightarrow c$ (as $x \rightarrow c'$) for $\lim_{x\rightarrow c'}f(x)= c$. If $f \rightarrow c$ and $g \rightarrow c$ as $x \rightarrow c'$, does it follow that $f \rightarrow g$ as $x \rightarrow c'$?

Comment: write out what you mean by $f\to g$ like you did for $f\to c$

Comment: I mean the same typical definition of the limit --See Brian Tung's answer. In retrospect I should have only tagged this as analysis rather than calculus as well.

Comment: The question wasn't for my sake, I just thought if you wrote it out it would become clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Semi-formally, suppose we want $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to be within $\varepsilon$ of each other in a punctured neighborhood of $x$ around $c'$.  Then we find $\delta$ such that both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are within $\varepsilon/2$ of $c$ in a punctured neighborhood of $x$ around $c'$.  Then, because $|f(x)-g(x)| \leq \varepsilon/2 + \varepsilon/2 = \varepsilon$, we are done.